# How to apply keystore/truststore pair

Tags: java, ssl

I created my own keystore.jks and truststore.jks using java's keytool. I need to know how to actually use them in the code.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/keystore.jks");
    SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory;
    SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = null;
    SSLSocket sslsocket = null;
    try {
        sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory
                .getDefault();
        sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory
                .createServerSocket(PORT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: "
                + Integer.toString(PORT));
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

That doesn't work. I'm trying to set up a client-server pair using my created stuff. If anyone could explain how I designate my pair for SSL I would appreciate it. Thanks.